# Python pandas: automatic conversion of string to Timestamp when constructing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> pd.version.short_version
'0.15.2'

>>> D = [{'time':pd.Timestamp('2000/01/01'), 'value':1},{'time':'----', 'value':3}]
>>> pd.DataFrame(D)

        time  value
0 2000-01-01      1
1 2015-03-03      3
```

The [1,'time'] cell has been automatically filled in. Seems this happens only when the non-time contains only characters like '-', '/' which are typically used in datetime.

```
>>> D = [{'time':'0', 'value':3}, {'time':pd.Timestamp('2000/01/01'), 'value':1}]
>>> pd.DataFrame(D)

                  time  value
0                    0      3
1  2000-01-01 00:00:00      1
```

Is this a bug or can I stop this?